# Is it possible to show custom comment metadata in the admin panel?

Tags: comments, wp-admin, comment-meta

I've customized my comment form with a new field (city, but that doesn't really matter). I've hooked and filtered and added my comment metadata with add_comment_metadata.

I want to show that metadata in the Comments admin panel (wp-admin/edit-comments.php). Google searches prove fruitless.

**Is this possible? If it is, how does one go about it?**

I'd like to show it in the author column, but I'll settle for viewing the metadata in the edit view for each individual comment.

Comment: Where exactly in the admin UI? Please edit your question to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To show the content on individual edit pages you need to add custom meta boxes to the comment edit page.  You'll use the key `comment` for the `$page` argument of `add_meta_box`.

```
<?php
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_comment', 'pmg_comment_tut_add_meta_box' );
function pmg_comment_tut_add_meta_box()
{
    add_meta_box( 'pmg-comment-title', __( 'Comment Title' ), 'pmg_comment_tut_meta_box_cb', 'comment', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function pmg_comment_tut_meta_box_cb( $comment )
{
    $title = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'pmg_comment_title', true );
    wp_nonce_field( 'pmg_comment_update', 'pmg_comment_update', false );
    ?>
    <p>
        <label for="pmg_comment_title"><?php _e( 'Comment Title' ); ?></label>;
        <input type="text" name="pmg_comment_title" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" class="widefat" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
```

You'll also probably want to be able to save changes from the admin.  You can hook into `edit_comment` to do that.

```
<?php
add_action( 'edit_comment', 'pmg_comment_tut_edit_comment' );
function pmg_comment_tut_edit_comment( $comment_id )
{
    if( ! isset( $_POST['pmg_comment_update'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['pmg_comment_update'], 'pmg_comment_update' ) )
        return;
    if( isset( $_POST['pmg_comment_title'] ) )
        update_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'pmg_comment_title', esc_attr( $_POST['pmg_comment_title'] ) );
}
```

I wrote a [tutorial](https://www.pmg.com/blog/adding-extra-fields-to-wordpress-comments/) about this if you're interesting in learning more -- the code snippets above are from it.

To show data in the comment list table is similar to [adding custom columns to post list tables](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/27/custom-columns-for-custom-post-types).

To make sure we get the right screen, hook into `load-edit-comments.php`, grab the current screen and then hook into `manage_{$screen->id}_columns` to add another column to the comment list table.

```
<?php
add_action('load-edit-comments.php', 'wpse64973_load');
function wpse64973_load()
{
    $screen = get_current_screen();

    add_filter("manage_{$screen->id}_columns", 'wpse64973_add_columns');
}
```

The function you hook into `manage_{$screen->id}_columns` just needs to alter the associative array to include the column.  It's a `$key => $label` pair -- make sure to remember the key, we'll use it later.  Going to stick with the comment title stuff above.

Finally, we need to hook into `manage_comments_custom_column` to echo out the comment title in the actual list table.  This is pretty straight forward.  I used a switch statement here because easily expandable to include more custom columns.

Any column `$key` you added earlier will be the first argument passed into the hooked function.

```
<?php
add_action('manage_comments_custom_column', 'wpse64973_column_cb', 10, 2);
function wpse64973_column_cb($col, $comment_id)
{
    // you could expand the switch to take care of other custom columns
    switch($col)
    {
        case 'title':
            if($t = get_comment_meta($comment_id, 'pmg_comment_title', true))
            {
                echo esc_html($t);
            }
            else
            {
                esc_html_e('No Title', 'wpse64973');
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

The code from the comment tut and the above stuff for custom list table columns is [here as a plugin](https://gist.github.com/1233407).

Comment: Excellent answer! Comprehensive and clear. Rather than a whole new column, could I append this to the Author column, without wrecking the rest of the data in the Author column? My guess is probably, but how?

Comment: No, there's not really an easy way to do that. You should take a look at the `WP_List_Table` class, a subclass of which is used to display the comments. Basically it dispatches each column to a method called `column_{$key}`, if that doesn't exist, it falls to back to `column_default`.  If you look at the callback for the [author column](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-comments-list-table.php#L448) there are no hooks to use.

Comment: Hi there, great answer. Would you fix the URL to pmg.co? It doesn't lead to the article that it should (just a blank page).