# Show Custom Comment Fields when editing in admin

Tags: custom-field, comments, wp-admin

I'm using the [Custom Comment](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/customcomment/) plugin to add custom fields to my comments.

> This plugin lets you define more fields for comment to let your visitors include their facebook, twitter and ... in their comments

Everything is working as expected. However, the custom fields don't show up when I edit a comment in the admin side.  Currently it only shows the default fields - `name`, `email`, `url`, `comment`.

Is there an action or a filter that can be used to show this comments custom fields?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inserting a meta box in the Comment edit screen is the same as in the post types screens. But it can only be placed on the wide column, the sidebar seems not to accept other boxes.

To capture the data that's being posted, I only found the filter [`comment_edit_redirect`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-admin/comment.php#L282).

This has to be adapted to work with the plugin. The custom field in this example is `meta_comment_field`. See code comments:

```
// SAVE COMMENT META
// only found this hook to process the POST
add_filter( 'comment_edit_redirect',  'save_comment_wpse_82317', 10, 2 );

// META BOX
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_box_wpse_82317' );

/**
 * Save Custom Comment Field
 * This hook deals with the redirect after saving, we are only taking advantage of it
 */
function save_comment_wpse_82317( $location, $comment_id )
{
    // Not allowed, return regular value without updating meta
    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['noncename_wpse_82317'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) 
        && !isset( $_POST['meta_comment_field'] ) 
        ) 
        return $location;

    // Update meta
    update_comment_meta( 
        $comment_id, 
        'meta_comment_field', 
        sanitize_text_field( $_POST['meta_comment_field'] ) 
    );

    // Return regular value after updating  
    return $location;
}

/**
 * Add Comment meta box 
 */
function add_custom_box_wpse_82317() 
{
    add_meta_box( 
        'section_id_wpse_82317',
        __( 'Meta Comment Meta' ),
        'inner_custom_box_wpse_82317',
        'comment',
        'normal'
    );
}

/**
 * Render meta box with Custom Field 
 */
function inner_custom_box_wpse_82317( $comment ) 
{
    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'noncename_wpse_82317' );

    $c_meta = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'meta_comment_field', true );
    echo "<input type='text' id='meta_comment_field' name='meta_comment_field' value='", 
        esc_attr( $c_meta ), 
        "' size='25' />";
}
```

[image: comments custom field]

Comment: Thanks for giving such a detailed answer, brasofilo. Much appreciated.  I'm very new to WordPress, so I'll have a play with the code and get back to you.

Comment: With the help of brasofilo, I understand the concept and got everything working :) This post was also useful: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64973/is-it-possible-to-show-custom-comment-metadata-in-the-admin-panel

Comment: @Chris, very nice related Q, thanks for bringing it up :)

Comment: @brasofilo how its possible to add metabox in side ?